# Model not detected by Django, even with `app_label` referencing to an existing app

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with an application called `application`.

The app is installed in the `INSTALLED_APPS` as follows:

```
### application/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'application.apps.MyAppConfig',
]
```

with the `AppConfig`:

```py
### application/apps.py


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'application'
    verbose_name = 'My App'
    label = 'application'

    path = f"{os.environ.get('APP_DIR')}/application"
    default = True
```

I have the models defined like this:

```py
### data/models/basemodel.py

from django.db import models

class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
   
   # ...  fields ...

   Meta:
      app_label: `application`
```

Project's tree:

```
main_dir/
  data/
    __init__.py
    models/
       __init__.py
       basemodel.py
  application/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    urls.py
    settings.py
    ...
```

Django is not finding the models, and if I run `makemigrations` Django responds `No changes detected`, and on `migrate`, the app `application` does not appear on the `Operations to perform`.

I want to split the data layer from the logic and interface layers. In order to do so, I've the models and other data-related business inside `data` (outside any installed app)

The goal is to link the models to the app from there, without having to declare any model inside the `application` dir.

The Model should be detected so the Django detects migrations to apply.

---

Context:

- Django Application reference: [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#application-configuration)
- Django Models reference: [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#app-label)

Comment: Did you generate the app with the cli?

Comment: No, I did not. In addition, the models are outside the app.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in the models directory?

Comment: Yes, it's a module.

Comment: So far the code you show seems legit.
Your import statement is correct? ej: from django.db import models -
Could you add some more details on the architecture of your project directory?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have a single module per model ? If so, you need to import your models inside `models\__init__` like so:

```
from .basemodel import BaseModel
```

I also suggest that you define `__all__` inside your init file, in order to import your models easily in other parts of the app:

```
__all__ = ["BaseModel"]

from .basemodel import BaseModel
```